# Floating div on scroll WITH START&END POINT (!)

Tags: html, web, floating

what I want on my site is a div that follows when you scroll, well, this is not so difficult as there are many sites that explain how to do it. But what I could not find was how I could set a start and end position.

I want the sidebar to start to float when the top of the window touches it and I want it to stop when it is at the bottom of the container, now it floats over the footer.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, with jQuery I calculated the `scrollTop();` and when it reached the point, for example 250px I did `addClass('fixed');` to make it fixed and stay at the page.

To let it stay at the bottom at a certain point I calculated the bottom margin and when it reached the given bottom margin I did `removeClass('fixed').css({position: 'absolute', bottom: '0px'});` to let it stay on the bottom of it's parent 100% height div.

I hope you understand.